# Codeigniter RewriteRule for controller

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have this url: http://domain.any/enfermedades_dermatologicas/term/181

I would like to skip the name of the method "term" so the result be something like this
http://domain.any/enfermedades_dermatologicas/181

I tried with the following rewrite rules but it's not working:

```
RewriteRule ^enfermedades_dermatologicas/(.+) /enfermedades_dermatologicas/term/$1
RewriteRule ^enfermedades_dermatologicas/(.+) /index.php/enfermedades_dermatologicas/term/$1
```

The controller function structure is the following:

```
public function term( $id_contenido ){ ... }
```

Please any help would be apreciated, sorry for my survival english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using *.htaccess*, you could use the following *[route](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)*:

```
$route['enfermedades_dermatologicas/(:num)'] = 'enfermedades_dermatologicas/term/$1';
```

This route will map a URL with 'enfermedades_dermatologicas' as the first segment and any number as the second segment, to the `enfermedades_dermatologicas` controller and the `term` function within that controller, with the number in the URL as the function's parameter.